# Using Join and Union All in one Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, union

Ok guys what this code does wrong is that it only displays the results from the part after the union all segment. I am unable to display the part before union all.

What I want this code to do is to display the results that have the same productid and where the voucherno matches in TBLGRN,TBLUPGRN and TBLINV.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
sqlGRN = "select g.ProductID,g.Qty as GRNQTY,i.qty as InvQty,g.VoucherNo," & _
     "g.CostPrice,i.ItemPrice as SellPrice from" & _
     " tblupgrn g left join tblinv i on g.voucherno=i.invoiceno where supplier='" & IgridCustomers.cellValue(IgridCustomers.CurRow, "Customer") & " and" & _
     " i.productid=g.productid' group by g.productid," & _
     "g.qty,g.costprice,g.voucherno,I.ITEMPRICE,i.qty union all" & _
    " select g2.ProductID,g2.Qty as GRNQTY,i2.qty as InvQty,g2.VoucherNo," & _
    "g2.CostPrice,i2.itemprice as SellPrice" & _
    " from tblgrn g2 left join tblinv i2 on g2.voucherno=i2.invoiceno where supplier='" & IgridCustomers.cellValue(IgridCustomers.CurRow, "Customer") & "' and" & _
    " i2.productid=g2.productid group by g2.productid," & _
    "g2.qty,g2.costprice,g2.voucherno,I2.ITEMPRICE,i2.qty"
```

The above is the actual query.

I have Tables Named TBLGRN,TBLUPGRN,TBLINV

TBLGRN & TBLUPGRN has the following columns

```
Supplier|ProductID|Qty|VoucherNO
```

TBLINV has the following columns

```
ProductID|ItemPrice|Qty|InvoiceNo
```

I have the following data on TBLGRN

```
Supplier|PRODUCTID||QTY  |VOUCHERNO|COSTPRIE  

Muzamil |1        |10    |12345    |100  
Muz5    |2222     |12    |12346    |200
```

I have the following data on TBLUPGRN

```
Supplier|PRODUCTID|QTY  |VOUCHERNO|COSTPRICE  

Iddi    |15       |10   |2456     |150  
Sumo    |50       |200  |7869     |350
```

The following Data is in the TBLINV table

```
PRODUCTID|ITEMPRICE|QTY|INVOICENO  

1        |150      |10 |12345  
50       |500      |200|7869  
2222     |400      |200|12346  
15       |300      |10 |2456
```

The result I am getting is this

```
PRODUCTID|GRNQTY|INVQTY|VOUCHERNO|COSTPRICE|SELLPRICE  

1        |10    |10    |12345    |100      |150  
2222     |12    |12    |12346    |200      |400
```

I want this result

```
PRODUCTID|GRNQTY|INVQTY|VOUCHERNO|COSTPRICE|SELLPRICE  

1        |10    |10    |12345    |100      |150  
2222     |12    |12    |12346    |200      |400  
50       |200   |200   |7869     |350      |500  
15       |10    |10    |2456     |150      |300
```

I hope I explained well.

NB: I have reduced the previous code, just omitted some unnecessary columns.

Comment: what RDBMS you are using and please add sample data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please evaluate the string and post the actual SQL query.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time guys, but i managed to answer my own question. I was actually missing an apostrophe on this line.

sqlGRN = "select g.ProductID,g.Qty as GRNQTY,i.qty as InvQty,g.VoucherNo," & _
     "g.CostPrice,i.ItemPrice as SellPrice from" & _
     " tblupgrn g left join tblinv i on g.voucherno=i.invoiceno where supplier=***'" & IgridCustomers.cellValue(IgridCustomers.CurRow, "Customer") & "*** and" & _

Answer (score 0):

ft join tblinv i on g.voucherno=i.invoiceno where supplier='" & IgridCustomers.cellValue(IgridCustomers.CurRow, "Customer") & " and" & _
         "i.productid=g.productid' group by g.grndate,g.productid,g.partno," & _

if you check this line " and" & _ "i.productid=
there is no space in it, so the sql become andi.productid

next time you can print the sql variable and run in sql program, it easier to debug

Comment: Srry my bad, it's because i have copied it badly may be. All the spaces and punctuation's are correct in the editor, the query also runs fine. The only problem is that it only displays results o the part after the union all.